# notmuch doesn't show INBOX ("Spawning child process: Invalid argument")

Tags: microsoft-windows, email, bash, notmuch

I'm trying to get `notmuch` working on Windows 10 using WSL/Ubuntu. The idea is to treat the WSL as a remote machine (roughly following https://notmuchmail.org/remoteusage/) and to have a shell script that executes `notmuch` within the WSL. The script file looks like this (called `notmuch.bat`):

```
@echo off

bash -c "notmuch %*"
```

Next, I've told `notmuch` to use this script file with `(setq notmuch-command "notmuch.bat")` and also added it to the `PATH` variable.

When starting `notmuch` in emacs, I can see the correct number of mails indexed by `notmuch` in `notmuch-hello`, but when I follow the "inbox" link, no mails are shown in `*notmuch-saved-search-inbox*`. Instead there is the message `Spawning child process: Invalid argument`.

Any idea what could be causing this?